# Best place to place/use my business logic

Tags: angular

I'm struggling with the best place to put my business logic.  I have it working right now but it doesn't feel right so any advice is appreciated.

I have a class that represent my entity

```
export class Order extends EntityBase  {

static initializer(entity: Order) { }

constructor() {
  super()
}

isRush: boolean

// Generated code. Do not place code below this line.
id: number;
description: string;
installDate: Date;
masterId: number;
master: Master;
}
```

I create a service to place my business logic

```
@Injectable()
export class OrderLogicService {

constructor() {}

  public calculateRush(start, end, holidays: Holiday[]) {
    //business rules here

  return true; 
  }
}
```

And I currently using it in my order service where I get the data from my api.  My gut tells me this is wrong but I'm not sure where else to put it where I won't have to call it multiple times.

```
@Injectable()
export class OrderService {
  urlBase: string = environment.urlBaseOld;
  private _em: EntityManager = new EntityManager(environment.urlBaseBreeze);

constructor(private http: Http,
  private orderLogic: OrderLogicService) {

  config.initializeAdapterInstance("uriBuilder", "json");
  RegistrationHelper.register(this._em.metadataStore);
  }

getMaster(id: number): Promise<Master> {
  let promise = new Promise<Master>((resolve, reject) => {
  let query = EntityQuery.from("Master").where("id", "==", id);
  let strategy: FetchStrategySymbol;

  strategy = FetchStrategy.FromServer;

  this._em.executeQuery(query.using(strategy)).then(
    queryResult => {
      let holidays = this.getHolidays()
      let master = <Master>queryResult.results[0]

        // *************   order.isRush field is set here using my business logic service
        master.orders.forEach(order => {
          order.isRush = this.orderLogic.calculateRush(
            order.master.submittedToIaOn, order.installDate, holidays) 
        })
        //**************************
        resolve(master);
      },
      error => reject(error)
    );
  });
  return promise;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services are the best place to put your bussiness logic. To keep your guts calm you could refactor your code and pull some private methods with descriptive names insteed of nested arrow functions. Apart from that, nothig wrong with the code and approach IMHO.